# "lateral join" equivalent in KDB?

Tags: join, kdb

How do  you "unpack" an array valued column in kdb ?

I have a table T which includes an array-valued column C,
and want a result with each the rows of T duplicated as many times as it has entries in the column C, with each duplicate containing one of the values from that column.

In PostgreSQL this would be a "lateral join".

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have the following table:

```
t:([]a:`a`b`c`d;b:(1,();(2;3);4,();(5;6;7)))

t
a b    
-------
a ,1   
b 2 3  
c ,4   
d 5 6 7
```

And you want duplicated rows for each value in column b, you can use `UNGROUP` to get:

```
q) ungroup t
a b
---
a 1
b 2
b 3
c 4
d 5
d 6
d 7
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to flatten nested columns is with the [`ungroup`](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/dictsandtables/#ungroup) command. This command will work where multiple nested columns exist, provided the lists in each row have the same length.

```
q)show tab:([]a:`a`b`c;b:(1#`d;`e`f;`g`h);c:(1#1;2 3;4 5))
a b    c
----------
a ,`d  ,1
b `e`f 2 3
c `g`h 4 5
q)ungroup tab
a b c
-----
a d 1
b e 2
b f 3
c g 4
c h 5
```

The downsides to this approach are that all nested columns are ungrouped and if there are different length lists in each row then the command will fail:

```
q)show tab2:([]a:`a`b`c;b:(1#`d;`e`f;`g`h);c:(1#1;2 3;1#4))
a b    c
----------
a ,`d  ,1
b `e`f 2 3
c `g`h ,4        / different length lists
q)ungroup tab2
'length
  [0]  ungroup tab2
       ^
```

One possible solution to ungroup by a single column is the following, which duplicates each row by the number of elements in each `c` value:

```
q)f:{[t;c]@[t where count each r;c;:;raze r:t c]}
q)f[tab2;`c]
a b    c
--------
a ,`d  1
b `e`f 2
b `e`f 3
c `g`h 4
```